# Am trying to recall the output of line 8 but still having problems

Tags: java

am trying to refer back to line 8 but don't know how, sorry am new to Java.
I've tried many approaches but still hitting a wall, pls what should I do.

```java
package Interview;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Interview {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println("hello,please what is your name:");
    System in = scanner(System.in);
    String Input=in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("well then welcome to startechz "+Input);
    System.out.println("Are you a male or female:");
    String Input=in.nextLine();
    if (Input=male)
    //recall outprint from line 8
      System.out.println("once again, welcome mr"+Input of Line8);
    else {
      System.out.println("once again,welcome mrs"+Input of Line8);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there many syntax error on your code it would be better to use ide

change this

```
System in = scanner(System.in);
```

to

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

you can  not redefine same variable again you have to statement

that looks like this

```
String Input=in.nextLine();
```

to solve this either use this

```
String newInput=in.nextLine();
```

or just assign new value to the same variable (of course of course if you do not want to use the old one again) like that

```
Input=in.nextLine();
```

in java to compare value you use double = sign like

```
Input==male
```

single = are used to assign value like int value = 5;

you can use == with primitive type only it will work but for reference type it will not work as in your case you use String with is reference type

why it did not work with reference type cause it will compare the reference address (the address for the object in memory (to be accurate it not the physical address but think of it like that))

so use the equal method

like

```
if (Input.equals("male")) // you forget also to make male as string you forget the double quotations
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if (Input=male)
```

to

```
if(Input.equalsIgnoreCase("male")) // allows case independent compare
```

Use `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings.